# CSV import in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a csv file that has column values enclosed within double quotes.

I want to import a csv file from a network path using an sql statement.

I tried bulk insert. But it imports along with double quotes. Is there any other way to import a csv file into SQL Server 2008 using an sql statement by ignoring the text qualifier double quote?

Thanks
-Vivek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [non-xml format file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479.aspx) to specify a different delimiter per column.  For values enclosed with double quotes, and delimited by tabs, the delimiter could be `\",\"`.  You'd have to add an initial unused column to capture the first quote.  For example, to read this file:

```
"row1col1","row1col2","row1col3"
"row2col1","row2col2","row2col3"
"row3col1","row3col2","row3col3"
```

You could use this format file:

```
10.0
4
1  SQLCHAR 0 50 "\""     0 unused ""
2  SQLCHAR 0 50 "\",\""  1 col1   ""
3  SQLCHAR 0 50 "\",\""  2 col2   ""
4  SQLCHAR 0 50 "\"\r\n" 3 col3   ""
```

(The number on the first line depends on the SQL Server version. The number on the second line is the number of columns to read. **Don't forget to adjust it**.)

The `bulk insert` command accepts a `formatfile = 'format_file_path'` parameter where you can specify the format file.  For example:

```
BULK INSERT YourTable
FROM 'c:\test\test.csv'
WITH (FORMATFILE = 'c:\test\test.cfmt')
```

This results in:

```
select * from YourTable
-->
col1        col2        col3
row1col1    row1col2    row1col3
row2col1    row2col2    row2col3
row3col1    row3col2    row3col3
```

Comment: Would this still leave you with a leading double-quote on your first field and a trailing double-quote on your last field?

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: You can capture the leading quote in an unused field, and the trailing quote in the terminator for the last field.  I've tested the example I posted and it works on SQL Server 2008 (which has BCP version 10.0)

Comment: +1 Nicely done. I wouldn't have thought of using an unused field for that leading quote.

Comment: Hi andomar, in my csv some columns will be enclosed within double quotes and some wont be. Is it possible to make this double quote optional?

_V

Comment: @Vivek Chandraprakash: Don't think so.  You could import without the quotes, and remove them like `update YourTable set col1 = substring(col1,2,len(col1)-2) where col1 like '"%"'`

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue when importing files with text delimiters as the bcp/bulk insert utilities don't allow you to specify a text delimiter. See [this link](http://jessesql.blogspot.com/2010/05/bulk-insert-csv-with-text-qualifiers.html) for a good discussion.

Answer (score 0):

@Andomar's anaswer got me 99% of the way there with a very similar problem. However, I found SQL Server 2014 failed to import the last row because the last field didn't have the new line characters: `\r\n`.
So my format file looked more like:

```
12.0
4
1   SQLCHAR 0   50  "\""    0   unused  ""
2   SQLCHAR 0   50  "\",\"" 1   col1    ""
3   SQLCHAR 0   50  "\",\"" 2   col2    ""
4   SQLCHAR 0   50  "\""    3   col3    ""
```

And so for my file, which had a row with field names, the import SQL became:

```
BULK INSERT MyTable
FROM 'C:\mypath\datafile.csv'
WITH (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\mypath\formatfile.cfmt',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
)
```

The actual CSV had 40 fields so it was helpful to read on [Microsoft's website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479.aspx) that it is not necessary to write the column names (`col1` - `col40` works just fine) and also that the fourth parameter in each line - `50` in the example, just needs to be the **maximum** field length, not exact.