# How do I BULK INSERT with additional column showing filename?

Tags: sql-server

I'm still getting used to SQL, so before I get to using stored procedure, I would like to understand how to use BULK INSERT effectively first.

I need to combine 50+ csv files and dump them into an SQL table. The problem is, I'd like to be able to tell each record apart (as in, each record belongs to a certain csv file, which I will identify by the file name).

Here's a small example of what I want:

```
CREATE TABLE ResultsDump
(
    PC FLOAT,
    Amp VARCHAR(50),
    RCS VARCHAR(50),
    CW VARCHAR(50),
    State0 VARCHAR(50),
    State1 VARCHAR(50),
)
BULK INSERT ResultsDump
    FROM 'c:\distance1000_7_13_2010_1_13PM_Avery DennisonAD_2300008_10S_Lock.csv' 
    WITH 
    ( 
        FIRSTROW = 2, 
        MAXERRORS = 0, 
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
BULK INSERT ResultsDump
    FROM 'c:\distance1000_7_13_2010_2_27PM_Avery DennisonAD_2300009_10S_Lock.csv' 
    WITH 
    ( 
        FIRSTROW = 2, 
        MAXERRORS = 0, 
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
BULK INSERT ResultsDump
    FROM 'C:\distance1000_7_13_2010_2_58PM_Avery DennisonAD_230000A_10S_Lock.csv' 
    WITH 
    ( 
        FIRSTROW = 2, 
        MAXERRORS = 0, 
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
BULK INSERT ResultsDump
    FROM 'c:\distance1000_7_13_2010_3_21PM_Avery DennisonAD_230000B_10S_Lock.csv' 
    WITH 
    ( 
        FIRSTROW = 2, 
        MAXERRORS = 0, 
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
BULK INSERT ResultsDump
    FROM 'c:\distance1000_7_13_2010_3_41PM_Avery DennisonAD_230000C_10S_Lock.csv' 
    WITH 
    ( 
        FIRSTROW = 2, 
        MAXERRORS = 0, 
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
```

I know this is an inefficient way of doing things, but I definitely like to figure out how to manually dump one file in the SQL table in the format I want before I start to create a stored procedure.

In the new table, I want something like this:

```
FileName,PC,Amp,RCS,CW,State0,State1
c:\distance1000_7_13_2010_1_13PM_Avery DennisonAD_2300008_10S_Lock.csv, ...
...
...
c:\distance1000_7_13_2010_2_27PM_Avery DennisonAD_2300009_10S_Lock.csv, ...
...
...
c:\distance1000_7_13_2010_2_58PM_Avery DennisonAD_230000A_10S_Lock.csv, ...
...
...
```

Any simple suggestions or referrals to specific functions would be great! Remember, I'm getting used to SQL and it'd be great if I could take this one step at a time, that's why I'm starting with such a simple question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BULK INSERT is not a standard SQL statement.  It would be sensible to tag this with the correct DBMS - I suspect MS SQL Server, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a column `FileName varchar(max)` to the ResultsDump table, create a view of the table with the new column, bulk insert into the view, and after every insert, set the filename for columns where it still has its default value `null`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ResultsDump
(
    PC FLOAT,
    Amp VARCHAR(50),
    RCS VARCHAR(50),
    CW VARCHAR(50),
    State0 VARCHAR(50),
    State1 VARCHAR(50),
)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ResultsDump ADD [FileName] VARCHAR(300) NULL 
GO 

CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_ResultsDump AS
SELECT
    PC,
    Amp,
    RCS,
    CW,
    State0,
    State1
FROM
    ResultsDump
GO

BULK INSERT vw_ResultsDump
    FROM 'c:\distance1000_7_13_2010_1_13PM_Avery DennisonAD_2300008_10S_Lock.csv' 
    WITH 
    ( 
        FIRSTROW = 2, 
        MAXERRORS = 0, 
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )

UPDATE dbo.ResultsDump 
SET [FileName] = 'c:\distance1000_7_13_2010_1_13PM_Avery DennisonAD_2300008_10S_Lock.csv'
WHERE [FileName] IS NULL 

BULK INSERT vw_ResultsDump
    FROM 'c:\distance1000_7_13_2010_2_27PM_Avery DennisonAD_2300009_10S_Lock.csv' 
    WITH 
    ( 
        FIRSTROW = 2, 
        MAXERRORS = 0, 
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )

UPDATE dbo.ResultsDump 
SET [FileName] = 'distance1000_7_13_2010_2_27PM_Avery DennisonAD_2300009_10S_Lock.csv'
WHERE [FileName] IS NULL
```

Comment: But in this case, the column numbers don't agree, so I can't use BULK INSERT?

Comment: @Think Blue Crew: Doesn't bulk insert ignore additional columns at the end of the table?  If not, you'd have to specify a format file.  For an example see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526136/csv-import-in-sql-server-2008/3526237#3526237

Comment: @Think Blue Crew: you can use Andomar's answer by adding the FileName column to your ResultsDump table, creating a view *without* the FileName column, bulk inserting into the view, and then updating the FileName column in the original table.

Comment: @8kb: Hi, I'm trying something similar and I'm wondering if you could help explain the process you described of "adding the FileName column to your ResultsDump table, creating a view without the FileName column, bulk inserting into the view, and then updating the FileName column in the original table"?

Comment: @Walker, I edited the answer to show exactly how it would look.

Comment: @8kb: Wow, thank you SO much. I hope others get as much value from this as I have.

Comment: This is a neat little trick. I modified the 'WHERE [FileName] IS NULL' part of the query to modify other default values, allowing more than one column to be updated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: This is an excellent answer, but I think it can be simplified for many cases - create the table dbo.ResultsDump, then do the bulk insert directly into that table. Then, alter that table to add the [Filename] column, and finally execute the update statement to set the value of the [Filename] column. No need to wrap your mind around views.

This will work for temporary load tables, etc., where you can re-create the table with only the columns that match the bulk insert every time you want to load a file. For loading into existing tables, using the view as shown is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
                    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReadandUpdateFileNames_SP]
            (
             @spRequestId NVARCHAR(50)
            ,@LoopCounter INT =0
            ,@MaxFIVId INT=0
            ,@spFileName NVARCHAR(100)=NULL)
            AS
            BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON
                BEGIN TRY
                    BEGIN TRAN
                    -- To read filename's from the Request Id and store it in a temp table
                        DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(500)
                        SET @cmd = 'dir D:\Input\REQUEST-'+@spRequestId+' /b '
                        --PRINT @cmd
                        DECLARE  @DirOutput TABLE(
                                      ID INT IDENTITY
                                    , files varchar(500))

                        INSERT INTO @DirOutput 
                        EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd
                        SELECT * FROM @DirOutput WHERE files IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID

                        ----Read files by RequestId BEGIN

                        SELECT @LoopCounter = min(ID) , @MaxFIVId = max(ID)
                            FROM @DirOutput 

                        WHILE(@LoopCounter IS NOT NULL AND @LoopCounter<@MaxFIVId)
                        BEGIN
                        -- Create temp table to store FIVItems 
                            CREATE  TABLE Items_TEMP  
                            (
                                  ControlID NVARCHAR(50)
                                , UNRS_Code NUMERIC(18,0)
                                , UNRS_Code_S NUMERIC(18,0)
                                , Ordered_Quantity NUMERIC(18,3)
                                , Sent_Quantity NUMERIC(18,3)
                                , Accepted_Quantity NUMERIC(18,3)
                                , Unit_Food_Price NUMERIC(18,2)
                                , Total_Price NUMERIC(18,2)
                            )
                        SELECT @spFileName=files FROM @DirOutput WHERE ID=@LoopCounter
                            PRINT @LoopCounter
                            DECLARE @spControlId NVARCHAR(50)
                            SET @spControlId='FFO'+ Substring(@spFileName, 4, (len(@spFileName)-7)) 
                            --PRINT @spControlId
                            DECLARE @sqlCmd NVARCHAR(MAX)
                            SET @sqlCmd='BULK INSERT 
                            Items_TEMP
                            FROM ''D:\Input\REQUEST-'+@spRequestId+'\'+@spFileName+'''
                            WITH(
                                  FIELDTERMINATOR='',''
                                , ROWTERMINATOR=''\n''
                            )'
                            PRINT @sqlCmd
                            EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCmd
                            ---Add a new column to the table which is not present in the CSV
                            ALTER TABLE Items_TEMP ADD OrderId NUMERIC(18,0)NULL
                            UPDATE Items_TEMP SET ControlID=@spControlId,OrderId=(SELECT OrderId FROM dbo.Orders WHERE ControlID=@spControlId)
                            SELECT * FROM Items_TEMP

                            --DROP FIVItems_TEMP table once CSV output generated
                            DROP TABLE Items_TEMP


                            SET @LoopCounter=@LoopCounter+1
                        END
                    ----****END***
                    COMMIT TRAN
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    ROLLBACK TRAN
                    PRINT 'ROLLBACK'
                    PRINT Error_Message()
                    SELECT ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine;
                END CATCH
            SET NOCOUNT OFF
            END
```

Comment: Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and refine your answer if need. Just posting code may not be a good answer.