# How to read the first line and store the second element into a array to insert into SQL table in C#

Tags: c#, sql, arrays

I have a **csv text file which the user browses for.**

When the user gets the text file, the first line has to be read and the second element has to be written into a `Sql Table`.

The text file is big but the first two lines look as follows:

```
students_head   201502  
student_id  code amount
```

And I have a Sql Table with the following columns:

```
student_id  code amount month
```

**What I need to do is get the month which is in the first line of the text file and fill it every in the month columns for all rows.**

to look like this

```
student_id  code amount month
1234        mt11 1000   201502
1235        mt11 25000  201502
1236        ds33 7800   201502
```

The code I have at the moment looks as follows:

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = ".csv file|*.csv*";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    String file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    btnNext.Enabled = true;

    try
    {
        string connect = "Data Source=BRIAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=PSAHoldings; user id =sa; Password=kagiso";

        string table = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='t_original' AND xtype='U')" +
            "CREATE TABLE t_original (" +
            "empId varChar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," +
            "paycode varChar(10) NOT NULL," +
            "amount int NOT NULL," +
            "month int NOT NULL,"+
            ")";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand createTable = new SqlCommand(table, con);
        createTable.ExecuteNonQuery();


        String BulkInsert = "BULK INSERT t_original FROM_" +
            file + "_WITH (--FIRSTROW = 3," +
            "FIELDTERMINATOR = '|'," +
            "ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n')";

        SqlCommand bulkCmd = new SqlCommand(BulkInsert, con);
        bulkCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Exception Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you are using BULK INSERT skipping the first row, so you don't have any control on this. How big is this file to require this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Just read it -

```
string month = string.empty;
using(var reader = new StreamReader(file))
{
    string firstLine = reader.ReadLine();
    string[] splitedLine = firstLine.Split(';'); // or whatever delimiter You used
    month = splittedLine[1];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544526/how-do-i-bulk-insert-with-additional-column-showing-filename <- like this for example

Comment: It's kinda workarround. But You're right - bulk Insert is not intended to do such things.

Comment: I was just pointing that your answer is incomplete, not that it is wrong to use BULK INSERT per se. An UPDATE statement after the insert will do the task. Perhaps if this is a critical part of the code some performance testing with BULK INSERT/UPDATE against a read line by line could be done to choose the best path, but we don't have enough info on the context.

Comment: So with this said How can I get it into the `month` column after running a `BULK_INSERT`

Comment: @George if you look carefully to the answers in the link provided you will notice that the BULK INSERT is followed by an UPDATE command that set the missing column with the value desidered. You just need to do the same