# Format fields during bulk insert SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, formatting, bulkinsert

I am currently working on a project that requires data from a report generated by third party software to be inserted into a local SQL database. So far I have the data stored as a tab delimited .txt file and the following bulk insert SQL statement:

```
BULK INSERT ExampleTable
FROM 'c:\temp\Example.txt'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2, 
FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

The two problems I am encountering are, quotation marks around any value that includes it's own comma, and money signs in every field that has a dollar amount.

For instance one of the columns of the table is a description field and some of the values come out looking like:
"this is an example description, some more information, I don't know why the author would use commas in the first place here"

I don't care about the description field nearly as much as other fields that include dollar amounts. Each of these fields is already prefixed with a $ sign, so I have to set them as a nvarchar instead of a decimal or a float, which would be **A LOT** more useful for reporting. Furthermore, when the dollar amount is greater than 1000, the field will also contain a comma, and thus, quotation marks. ex "$1,084.59"

I am familiar with SSMS, but I have never made a format or bcp file (the solutions I have found online).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a format file, but only if your metadata remains constant, which it does not appear to be in your case.  You state that the dollar amounts are enclosed in quotes only when they exceed 999 and the comma is inserted.  A format file would allow you to define per column delimiters such as [,] or [","].  But if that delimiter is shifting throughout your file, you will have to pre-process the file.  Text qualifiers themselves are not supported.

For reference:

[CSV import in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526136/csv-import-in-sql-server-2008)

http://jessesql.blogspot.com/2010/05/bulk-insert-csv-with-text-qualifiers.html

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was reaching the same conclusion, that the data will have to be pre-processed.

Comment: One thing I've done in the past with success is import the data into a table with a raw string delimiting only on the row.  Then with a few views, you can build the pre-processing intelligence and then insert into a physical table from your views, or make a stored procedure out of it.

Answer (score 0):

i dont see why, but ThiefMaster deleted my answer :-(
probabaly a mistake and he did not check the link, as this link is the full answer to you question, i will try again for the last time here...

Tip: if your CSV file don't have consistent format, for example ON THE SAME COLUMN some of the values are doubleqouted and some not than this blog will help you do it in an easy way (using openrowset in the last step make it a one simple query): http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/122/Using-Bulk-Insert-to-import-inconsistent-data-format-using-pure-T-SQL.aspx

- There is a new WIKI at: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki based on this blog **if you prefer to read from Microsoft site.**